# Postman console.error does not show up for "else" statement

Tags: postman

Really easy one for most of you probably but I can't seem to get past this for some reason.

Problem being: when the Header is there, I get the message to console, but if it's missing, for some reason I don't.

I have tried else if statement also, can't get it working.

Maybe it would be better to use negative statements somehow? Thank you!

```
 pm.test("Getting images", function () {
  if (pm.response.to.be.header ("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")) {
  console.log("got the image");
  }
else
  console.error("failed to get the image");
    pm.response.to.be.header("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this help:

```
pm.test("Getting images", function () {
    if (pm.response.headers.get("Content-Type") === "image/jpeg") {
        pm.response.to.be.header("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
        console.log("Got the image");
    }
    else {
        console.error("Failed to get the image")
    }
});
```